# Select * from table@dblink in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

When I run query `select * from table@dblink` in PL/SQL Developer,[transaction commit/rollback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5pDe.jpg) icons are activated, but then if I use `Fetch last page` these icons are disabled. Why is this happening?

Comment: which tool are you using to run this query?

Comment: I use `PL SQL Developer 8.0`

Answer (score 1):

Querying over a db_link flips the 'we have a transaction' switch in the data dictionary

In most tools, you'll get a prompt for COMMIT or an indicator of an open transaction whenever you query against a DB_LINK.

That's because you're doing 'something' that's not clear to us in a different database. Your 'SELECT' could have side effects which require a COMMIT/ROLLBACK, or as [Tom would say](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4463542200346232696)

'If you are distributed, you would want to commit to finish off anything that was implicitly started on the remote site.'

Answer (score 0):

I think that PL/SQL is trying to remove useless transactions to help avoid session errors.  It seems that whenever you press the "Fetch last page" button, PL/SQL Developer runs `commit write batch` if the statement contains a database link, if there are no transactions currently open in the session, and if the statement does not include `FOR UPDATE`.

Those are a lot of weird conditions, but they seem to ensure that the program won't commit when it shouldn't.  I assume PL/SQL Developer is using `commit write batch` to use less resources than a normal `commit`.  That guess is based on the number returned by this query increasing when I hit the button.  (There's another statistic for `user commits`, and that number does not increase.)

```
select value
from v$mystat
join v$statname on v$mystat.statistic# = v$statname.statistic#
where lower(display_name) = 'commit batch performed';
```

This behavior is a little odd, but it could help prevent some errors in the session.  For example, if you later try to run `alter session enable parallel dml` the session would throw the error `ORA-12841: Cannot alter the session parallel DML state within a transaction`.  By committing the (worthless) transaction, you avoid some of those errors.